# Extending Stack Library

Tags: java, inheritance, stack, extend

I am trying to extend the stack library, but keep getting the following error messages:
found   : java.util.Stack
required: java.util.Stack[]

and

non-static class T cannot be referenced from a static context
            EStack a = new EStack  ();

My code is as follows:

```
public class EStack<T> extends Stack <T>{
    Stack [] stack;

    public EStack(){
        this.stack=new Stack();
    }

    public static void main(){
        EStack<T> a = new EStack <T> ();

        a.push("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You declare an `array` object (`Stack[]`), and then you're trying to assign `Stack` object to it. These are two different types.
2. And that snippet `EStack < T > a = new EStack < T > ();` makes really no sense, as you don't have that constructor, and I can't see any point of using generics here. Maybe you could explain this a bit more.
3. Don't create a `main()` method in your subclass! Use a separate `Main` class for testing your code.

Comment: I am trying to create a new class that extends the stack library class in Java so that I can (after this step) add another method to my new class. I am stuck on the extending the stack library step.